# Error when starting a project in Lean, 'binary package was not provided for 'windows''

Tags: lean, lean-mathlib, installation

after taking a break of half a year I would like to get back to proving things in Lean. I followed the [instructions](https://leanprover-community.github.io/install/project.html) to install a fresh lean project. When I do

`winpty leanproject new fresh_project`

in git bash, it starts creating the git repository andconfiguring, but then I get the error:

```
Adding mathlib
info: downloading component 'lean'
error: binary package was not provided for 'windows'
Command '['leanpkg', 'add', 'leanprover-community/mathlib']' returned non-zero e
xit status 1.
```

Does anyone know what I can do to get it running again?

Remark: `winpty` is just a workaround to get python running in the windows vresion of the `git bash`-command line, which I have used before.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to update `elan` because of upstream changes at github. Try `elan self update`. If this doesn't work then reinstall `elan`. If you search for your error on the lean Zulip you'll find lots more information about this (but hopefully you won't need it).

Comment: 'elan self update' worked. Thanks!